# Why Cant I Read/Write to Text File In Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, file-writing, file-read

I am trying to simply write a line of text to a file in Android Studio but for some reason whenever I run the line of code the application crashes.

```
fun editNote2 (buttonView: View) {

    File("/app/sampledata/NoteText.txt").writeText("Hello world!")

}
```

I am a beginner so a simple answer would be nice, if there even is such a thing.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-read-file

Comment: Provide the logcat.

Comment: `/app/sampledata/NoteText.txt` is not a valid filesystem path on Android devices. You are welcome to write to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), limited places on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and even fewer places on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should add *Read&Write* Permissions in **AndroidManifest** file. Please check below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```